# How to lock an element, so that the the html before it doesn't affect the lower text?

Tags: html, css

The sign is forcing the buttons to move down. I don't want this, as I want the sign to be in the right side of the screen. if you see the result, the buttons are under the sign. How do I avoid this. Absolute and relative positioning doesn't work because it just makes the elements overlap. I also want this to work for other elements when. I put them in. Thanks.

```css
:root {
    --gray: #343434; 
    --purple: #5e5ebe;
    --blue: #3495d9;
    --red: #ff3a41;
}
.header-right{
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: var(--red);
    color:rgb(3, 2, 2);
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    width:500px;
    margin:50px ;

  }
  .sign{
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    top:100px;
  }
#navbar{
    background: var(--gray);
    height: 51px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
   }
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#navbar ul, #navbar li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}
#navbar li {
    float: left;
}
/*#navbar span {
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
}*/
.centered{
    margin: auto;
}
#navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    display:flex;
    line-height: 51px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
}
#navbar li a:hover {
    color: #0099CC;
    background: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<nav id='navbar'>
        <ul>
          <p class="sign">Sign</p>
            <li class="centered"><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
          <li class="centered"><a href='#'>Updates</a></li>
          <li class="centered"><a href='#'>Who am I?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>**Is This The Result You Wanted ?**</s> **Code has been updated.**

```css
:root {
    --gray: #343434; 
    --purple: #5e5ebe;
    --blue: #3495d9;
    --red: #ff3a41;
    }
    .header-right{
    border-radius: 30px;
    background: var(--red);
    color:rgb(3, 2, 2);
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center; 
    width:500px;
    margin:50px ;

      }
      .sign{
    border-radius: 25px;
    float:right;
    background: red;
    padding: 15px; 
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
      }
    #navbar{
    background: var(--gray);
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
       }
    *{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    }
    #navbar ul, #navbar li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
    }
    #navbar li {
    float: left;
    }
    /*#navbar span {
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    }*/
    .centered{
    margin: auto;
    }
    #navbar a {
    display: inline-block;
    display:flex;
    line-height: 51px;
    padding: 0 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
    #navbar li a:hover {
    color: #0099CC;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      #navbar ul {
    margin:0;
      }
    }
```

```html
<nav id='navbar'>
        <ul>
          <p class="sign">Sign</p>
            <li class="centered"><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
          <li class="centered"><a href='#'>Updates</a></li>
          <li class="centered"><a href='#'>Who am I?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I don't want the sign to be centered.

Comment: That means you want the sign in the right corner with no spacing (not in the center) and the button in the center, to the left of the sign?

Comment: Example : 1 -> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfaB0.png)                                                       Example : 2 -> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwS3h.png)                                                       Which One Do You Want ?

Comment: I want the sign to be in the right corner, while the buttons stay in the middle of the screen.

Comment: @DarkDragon Sorry for the delayed reply, please check the updated code.